# Dropbox with whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backup, dropbox, dropbox-api, whenever

I'm trying to use whenever with dropbox. I created Core Api App on Dropbox site. After running whenever I got this error:

> Couldn't get access token.  Server returned 401: Unauthorized. Visit
>   the following URL to authorize your Dropbox App with Backup:
>   https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=0CV3BXK6enDIQe7H

After running this url I got

> The app My_App would like to connect with your Dropbox.

After hit on the Allow button:

> Success! Your Dropbox account is now connected with My_App

After all this I'am getting this error and in App Console on Dropbox site I can't turn My_App in production mode:

> Please test this app!There are no users linked to this app. Please
>   test this app's API integration with your my_email account before
>   applying for production status.

How correct to use Dropbox with whenever gem for backup my DB?